# Render template with params from another app (microservice)

Tags: python, django, microservices, httpresponse, url-parameters

I'm making a web app with a microservice architecture. When it comes to login I want to redirect the successfully logged in user to his dashboard (which is on another microservice). I have a problem with passing parameters such as `name`, `surname`, `email`, and `token`.

**microservice 1 (views.py):**

```
class SignInView(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def post(self, request):
        email = request.data['email']
        password = request.data['password']
        user = User.objects.filter(email=email).first()
        print(bool(user.is_coordinator))
        if user is None:
            messages.error(request, 'User not found. Please try again')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/sign-in')

        if not user.check_password(password):
            messages.error(request, 'Invalid password. Please try again')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/sign-in')

        payload = {
            'id': user.id,
            'exp': datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=60),
            'iat': datetime.datetime.utcnow()
        }

        token = jwt.encode(payload, 'secret', algorithm='HS256')

        response = Response()
        response.set_cookie(key='jwt', value=token, httponly=True)
        response.data = ({
            'jwt': token
        })

        if user.is_coordinator:
            return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8001/dashboard-coordinator')
        else:
            return HttpResponseRedirect('http://127.0.0.1:8001/dashboard-employee', {'name': user.name, 'surname': user.surname, 'email': user.email, 'response.data': response.data})
...
```

**microservice 2 (views.py):**

```
class HomeView(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'dashboard-employee.html', {'name': name, 'surname': surname, 'email': email, 'response.data': response.data})
```

What I've included in microservice 2 does not work. How can I get and process params from microservice 1? Is there any better solution/approach?

Comment: You may wish to consider using `views.APIViews` instead of `viewsets.ViewSet` based on how you are structuring your code. Compare how they are intended to be subclassed: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/ versus https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/.

Answer (score 0):

The Python context of these two microservices is not directly shared, but it wouldn't be shared in the way microservice 2 needs it right now, even if the `get()` and the `post()` were in the same microservice. Set aside the microservices and HTTP for a moment and imagine if we had these two functions side by side:

```py
def post():
    name = 'First'
    surname = 'Last'
    return get()

def get():
    return name, surname
```

We would get a NameError, because `name` and `surname` don't exist inside the scope of the `get()` function. So, how could we fix this? We could set up some sort of global state, but that's not necessary. Instead, we can pass some information from `post()` to `get()`:

```py
def post():
    name = 'First'
    surname = 'Last'
    data = {'name': name, 'surname': surname}
    return get(data)

def get(data):
    return data['name'], data['surname']
```

This is of course a silly example, but maybe you can already see the similarities between it and your real-world code. You have actually already done the work in `put()` to transmit the data, now in `get()` you need to grab it back out from `request.query_params`:

```py
class HomeView(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def get(self, request):
        name = request.query_params['name']
        surname = request.query_params['surname']
        email = request.query_params['email']
        response_data = request.query_params['response.data']
        return render(request, 'dashboard-employee.html', {'name': name, 'surname': surname, 'email': email, 'response.data': response_data})
```

Or more simply,

```py
class HomeView(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request, 'dashboard-employee.html', request.query_params)
```